# Shell - recording the output of the 'od' command to a variable

Tags: linux, shell

I read on a forum that to find a random string, you should use the following syntax:

```
od -a -A n /dev/urandom | head -30 | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '\n' | awk '{print substr($0,1,256)}'
```

how could I put this output to the variable 'var' instead of displaying it on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture it with backticks: <kbd>``</kbd>

```
VAR=`od -a -A n /dev/urandom | head -30 | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '\n' | awk '{print substr($0,1,256)}'`
```

Answer (score 3):

Use backticks or `$()`, i.e.

```
var=`command`
```

or

```
var=$(command)
```